# Import contact groups in ios

Tags: ios

I want to be able to import contact group data when I import contacts in my application. Is there a method for me to get this data from iOS or am I just limited to get contact details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I import contact information into my app. I store the info in an `NSDictionary` so I can read it back later easily. It's in no way pretty, but works very well.

### .h

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
{
}
@end
```

### .m

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark AddressBook Delegates

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
    return NO;
}
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    /* photo */
    CFDataRef imgeData = ABPersonCopyImageData(person);
    if(imgeData)
    {
        /* set an image to something using: (NSData*)imgeData */
        CFRelease(imgeData);
    }else{
        /* theres no photo */
    }

    CFStringRef email,emailLabel, phone,phoneLabel, url,urlLabel;
    //Phone Numbers
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSMutableDictionary *myPhoneDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneMulti)];
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneMulti); i++) { 
        phoneLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneMulti, i));
        phone = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneMulti, i); 
        [myPhoneDict setObject:(NSString*)phone forKey:(NSString*)phoneLabel];
        //NSLog(@"%@: %@",phoneLabel,phone);
        CFRelease(phone);
        CFRelease(phoneLabel);
    } 
    if ( [myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"mobile"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"mobile"]] forKey:@"Phone"];
    } else if ( [myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"home"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"home"]] forKey:@"Phone"];
    } else if ( [myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"work"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myPhoneDict objectForKey:@"work"]] forKey:@"Phone"];
    }

    //Email Address
    ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    NSMutableDictionary *myEmailDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMulti)];
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMulti); i++) { 
        emailLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emailMulti, i));
        email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailMulti, i); 
        [myEmailDict setObject:(NSString*)email forKey:(NSString*)emailLabel];
        CFRelease(email);
        CFRelease(emailLabel);
    } 
    if ([myEmailDict objectForKey:@"home"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[myEmailDict objectForKey:@"home"] forKey:@"EmailHome"];
    } else {
        [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Email"];
    } if ([myEmailDict objectForKey:@"work"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[myEmailDict objectForKey:@"work"] forKey:@"EmailWork"];
    } else {
        [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Email"];
    } if ([myEmailDict objectForKey:@"other"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[myEmailDict objectForKey:@"other"] forKey:@"EmailOther"];
    } else {
        [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Email"];
    }

    //Website Address
    ABMutableMultiValueRef URLMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonURLProperty);
    NSMutableDictionary *myURLDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(URLMulti)];
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(URLMulti); i++) { 
        urlLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(URLMulti, i));
        url = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(URLMulti, i); 
        [myURLDict setObject:(NSString*)url forKey:(NSString*)urlLabel];
        //NSLog(@"%@",myURLDict);
        CFRelease(url);
        CFRelease(urlLabel);
    } 

    if ([myURLDict objectForKey:@"home page"] != nil) {
        [plistDict setObject:[myURLDict objectForKey:@"home page"] forKey:@"Website"];
    }else{
        [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Website"];
    }

    //Full Address
    ABMultiValueRef streets = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
    //NSMutableDictionary *myAddressDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(streets)];
    for (CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(streets); j++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *myLabelDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(streets, j);
        CFStringRef typeTmp = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(streets, j);
        CFStringRef type = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(typeTmp);
        NSString *street = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey) copy];
        NSString *city = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey) copy];
        NSString *state = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey) copy];
        NSString *zip = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey) copy];
        NSString *country = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey) copy];

        if ((street != nil) && (street.length > 0)){
            [plistDict setObject:street forKey:@"Street"];
        }else{
            [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Street"];
        }

        if ((city != nil) && (city.length > 0)){
            [plistDict setObject:city forKey:@"City"];
        }else{
            [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"City"];
        }

        if ((state != nil) && (state.length > 0)){
            [plistDict setObject:state forKey:@"State"];
        }else{
            [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"State"];
        }

        if ((zip != nil) && (zip.length > 0)){
            [plistDict setObject:zip forKey:@"Zip"];
        }else{
            [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Zip"];
        }

        if ((country != nil) && (country.length > 0)){
            [plistDict setObject:country forKey:@"Country"];
        }else{
            [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"Country"];
        }

        if (type != nil){
            [plistDict setObject:(NSString *)type forKey:@"AddressType"];
        }else{
            [plistDict setObject:@"" forKey:@"AddressType"];
        }


        [myLabelDict release];
        [street release];
        [city release];
        [state release];
        [zip release];
        [country release];

        CFRelease(dict);
        CFRelease(type);
    }
    CFRelease(streets);
    CFRelease(phoneMulti);
    CFRelease(emailMulti);
    CFRelease(URLMulti);


    [plistDict writeToFile:current atomically:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self refreshViews];
    [tblAddCarrier reloadData];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Does this allow me to see the custom groups that iphone imports from other sources, but doesnt allow me to make?

Comment: You will need to make some changes, but you should be able to get the group the contact is in. YOu will have to explore the AddressBook framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)fetchMobileContacts
{

CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);

__block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) { // we're on iOS 6
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        accessGranted = granted;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
else { // we're on iOS 5 or older
    accessGranted = YES;
}

if (accessGranted) {
    // Do whatever you want here.
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );
    NSMutableArray *validAddress = [NSMutableArray new];
    for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
    {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumberProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSArray* phoneNumbers = (__bridge NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(phoneNumberProperty);

        ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        NSArray* emails = (__bridge NSArray*)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailProperty);

        NSString *email = @"";
        NSString *phone = @"";

        if(phoneNumbers.count) phone = [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:0];
        if(emails.count) email = [phoneNumbers objectAtIndex:0];
        if(email.length || phone.length){
            NSDictionary *contactInfo = @{kContactName: fullName, kContactPhone: phone, kContactEmail: fullName};
            [validAddress addObject:contactInfo];
        }
    }
    MobileContactsViewController *contactsVC = [[MobileContactsViewController alloc] initWithContacts:validAddress];
    contactsVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:contactsVC animated:YES];
}
}
```